# Setting a universal size for a scene in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, viewcontroller, skscene

In the documented SK programming guide by Apple the first displayed scene is "executed" by this code in the ViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
HelloScene* hello = [[HelloScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(768,1024)];
SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
[spriteView presentScene: hello];
}
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

Notice that it's a sample project for the iPad, so the view size is fixed (768, 1024).
How do I set it up, so that it could scale up nicely on an iPhone 4/5 (and probably the next gen iPhone)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the device's size and use this, for example:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenRect.size;
    HelloScene* hello = [[HelloScene alloc] initWithSize:screenSize];
    SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
    [spriteView presentScene: hello];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but everything in my app is out of scale now..(even though i didn't set the size of the buttons to a specific pixel size)
why is that?

Comment: Can you define "out of scale"? Not to state the obvious but consider that for a bigger screen size you'll need to make your images bigger, in points I mean.

Comment: Nvm I found my problem!